# SDK Version Issue in iOS 12.2 SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk

While uploading the app into test flight I'm getting this below error

> This app was built with the iOS 12.2 SDK. Starting April 2020, all iOS
>   apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or
>   later, included in Xcode 11 or later.

**Xcode Version 10.2.1**

**Swift Language version: Swift 5**

**Deployment target: 10.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already answered yourself,

> Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later.

so just update your xcode